# JSON Feed Object Not Set, PHP Wrapper Gives Unexpected Character

Tags: php, json

I am trying to import this JSON into VMIX (video mixing software) and I received the "object not set to an instance of an object" error:
https://scorestream.com/api?request=%7B%22method%22:%22teams.get%22,%22params%22:%7B%22apiKey%22:%22000000-YOUR-API-KEY-99999999999%22,%22teamIds%22:[4014]%7D%7D

After some investigating, I discovered that encoding may be a possibiltity. So I wrapped the JSON in PHP:

```
 <?php
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $string = file_get_contents("https://scorestream.com/api?request=%7B%22method%22:%22teams.get%22,%22params%22:%7B%22apiKey%22:%22000000-YOUR-API-KEY-99999999999%22,%22teamIds%22:[4014]%7D%7D");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
print_r($json_a);
die();
?>
```

The result is here:
http://www.columbus.k12.nc.us/sports/testscores.php

But vMix says on import "Encountered unexpected character 'A'.

I know I have fouled this up, but how can I get a compliant JSON feed from the initial link?

Comment: Your API is already returning a JSON encoded string. If I understood right, decoding it is the opposite of what you want. Did you already try to pass the JSON string as is? i.e. just `echo $string;`

Comment: @ishegg I used this with the same results object not set  `<?php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
$string = file_get_contents("https://scorestream.com/api?request=%7B%22method%22:%22teams.get%22,%22params%22:%7B%22apiKey%22:%22000000-YOUR-API-KEY-99999999999%22,%22teamIds%22:[4014]%7D%7D");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
echo $string;
die();
?>`

Comment: The unexpected character `A` is the beginning of `Array()`, this means vMix is expecting a string but is being fed an array.

Comment: So the initial link is a string correct?

Comment: show us a `var_dump($json_a);`  Perhaps you have a string that "looks" like an array printed to screen.